# Setting up the config file for a simple PHP login script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm creating a simple PHP login page for a site, but I'm having an issue querying the database properly since I'm not used to setting this kind of thing up. Can someone let me know what I'm missing here?

The basic premise is that the login page will just require a password which has been set in the P_page table under the field called "Password", but I'm not clear how to fully set that up.

Additionally, I realize some of what I'm using is depreciated, but I wasn't 100% clear on using the newer functions.

```
<?php
$db_username="XY";
$db_password="ZZ";
$db_name="XYZ";
$db_host="localhost";
$Plogin = mysql_pconnect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
?>

<?php 
mysql_select_db($db_name, $Plogin);
$query_iFp = "SELECT * FROM P_page ORDER BY title";
$rsiFp = mysql_query($query_iFp, $Plogin) or die(mysql_error());
$row_iFp = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsIfp);
?>

<?php
session_start();
$secured = false;
$password = "$row_iFp";
?>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Can you elaborate "page will just require a password which has been set in the P_page table under the field called `Password`, but I'm not clear how to fully set that up"? What does it means "require"? How to set what up?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to call the Password field from the database to be used as the value for $password at the end. There will only be one value in there, so it just needs to select the first one it finds. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do this:

```
$password = $row_iFp['Password'];
```

Also if you are selecting only the password field and you really only need 1 result, you could optimize the query to:

```
$query_iFp = "SELECT Password FROM `P_page` ORDER BY title LIMIT 0, 1";
```

Using `SELECT *` is usually considered bad practice. Always specify the fields that you are really gonna need.

Comment: Thanks! That worked like magic. Appreciate the help so quickly!